# Insert multiple rows into a single table from a textbox form - Access 2010

Tags: sql, database, vba

I have a table with a single field (defined as Number) in which I would like to insert multiple rows from a textbox in a form. The code is:

```
Private Sub CmdImportID_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

  strSQL = "DELETE * FROM [Con_ID futcanc BAMB]"  
  DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

  strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Con_ID futcanc BAMB] (con_id) VALUES (" & Me!conID & ");"   
  DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL    
 End Sub
```

Problem is: it works with a single number in textbox, but when I try to insert more than one I receive "Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression".
How can I modify the code to insert more data? Sorry, I'm not really skilled in coding vba :(

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the ">" character in (" & >Me!conID & ") it's a mistake, the code is without it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have written is for a single row insert and it will run only for one time.  If a seperator is present for the numbers in Textbox, then loop through each number by splitting the Text with seperator and insert as seperate rows in DB.

Generally

```
INSERT INTO [Con_ID futcanc BAMB] (con_id) VALUES (1)
```

will inserts only one row and

`INSERT INTO [Con_ID futcanc BAMB] (con_id) VALUES (1,2)` is Invalid statement.

EDIT:

Refer the below link for Split and Loop code Logic

[Split and Loop](https://science.nature.nps.gov/im/units/arcn/data_management/code/39.htm)

Comment: ok, thank you! And how can I modify the code for multiple rows?

Comment: Refer to Edited answer